# have two variables to be joined as a path using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i have two variables to be joined as a path,

```
SUITE_DIR = D:/Squish and 
SUITE_NAME = HMI_Remote
```

Now i want DIR_name as D:/Squish/HMI_Remote

when i tried

```
 os.path.join(SUITE_DIR,SUITE_NAME)
    it gave me D:/Squish\HMI_Remote
```

why is it so and how get it right ?

thanks in advance

Brijesh

Comment: Where do you get that SUITE_DIR value?

Comment: What's os.sep equal to?

Comment: SUITE_DIR is got from a tkinter window (through a browse button)

Answer (score 2):

In `os.path` there is a function `normpath`, which gets the input straight (and resolves relative parts and some further improvements).

Comment: Didn't know about that function, very useful.

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join` uses the `separator` of the OS, which in the case of Windows, is `\`. Windows can use either `\` or `/` though.

Just change `SUITE_DIR` to be `SUITE_DIR = 'D:\Squish'` and you'll be fine.

Comment: `'D:\Squish'` works but is a mistake waiting to happen, better `'D:\\Squish'`

Comment: 'D:/Squish' is coming from a browse button

Answer (score 0):

It looks you're running this python script under `Windows` and the path separator for `Windows` is `\` and not `/`.

You should have instead created the string `SUITE_DIR` using [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep)